# Licensing scripts

Tags: jquery, flash, actionscript, licensing

I've had my first nightmare client recently who was messing me around with payment for a project.

I've come to an agreement with another client to use some of the sites scripting to build a site for them. But, now the original client wants their site too.

I have made a deal to licence the reused parts of the site (some jQuery scripts and a dynamic flash gallery) rather than me signing over full copyright.

However, I haven't got a clue how to do this. Can anyone point me in the right direction to read up on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good book for understanding your rights with respect to your code as a programmer is "intellectual property and open source" (google it).  It covers copyrights and licensing.  It's geared towards programmers and makes no assumptions you know anything about law.  I got it for $10 on safari online.  I'd check it out before paying for lawyer.

Answer (score 1):

call a lawyer and get him to write a generic contract that you can reuse, whereby you retain all rights of resale, but the client retains a right to use.

legal advice from stackoverflow won't solve your problem.  you definitely want a real lawyer to handle things like this.

Comment: I've only recently had contracts drawn up, they allow for signing a release of copyright or licening. Can't really afford a trip back yet tho & don't have a default licence yet. Thanks for the reponse anyhow.